# Android heap memory error when using webview

Tags: android, webview

I have an android application that is using a webview in order to display some informations from a site.
The problem that I am having is when I try to navigate between pages within the site. I am receiving the following error after which the application crashes:

`@@@ ABORTING: HEAP MEMORY CORRUPTION IN dlmalloc
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)`

After reading some posts I have disabled the cache and I have added a WebChromeClient in the **onCreate** method which I am using to load the site, but the app still crashes with the same error

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webView.loadUrl("the_url_address");
```

Android version which I am using is 4.0.3. Also, the site loaded is making some asynchronous requests, but I don't thinks this should be a problem.
**Note:** I have also tested with Android 4.4.2 and the issue is not reproducing

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a segfault. Please post the whole log. Thx.

Comment: There is no more log information before this error. Even though I put on verbose, the error comes only with those 2 lines.

Comment: And after that, no further logs at all? Please check, if your logcat filters are disabled, to see all messages.

Comment: I have checked again and I have not seen any other error (or info) written. The 2 lines mentioned in the main post are the last written in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be from my messed up operating system (maybe caused by installing/uninstalling broken apps).

After some time this issue occured I had some performance problems with my phone and I had to reinstall the operating system. After this refresh, the problem did not occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In AndroidMainfest.xml

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:largeHeap="true"    

<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:largeHeap="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="HelloWorld" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: As I understood from your post, I have added **android:hardwareAccelerated** and **android:largeHeap** attributes (with true values) in the <manifest/> tag and in the <application/> tag, but the error reproduces the same way. Also, I have **android:hardwareAccelerated** attribute set to **true** within all activities, but no good result.

Comment: largeHeap is for a larger dalvik heap whereas the error reported is a corrupt native heap (therefore will not have any effect).

Comment: @JonnyBoy you may have right because after reinstalling the operating system, the issue did not reproduce anymore.